# Finding rank and nullity of 3X4 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am given

\begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 1 & 1 & 1           \\[0.3em]
       1 & 2           & 4 & 2 \\[0.3em]
       2 & 0         & -4 & 1
     \end{bmatrix}

I know that I need to get it in reduced row echelon form so I first do $-R_1 + R_2$ to get.

\begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 1 & 1 & 1           \\[0.3em]
       0 & 1           & 3 & 1 \\[0.3em]
       2 & 0         & -4 & 1
     \end{bmatrix}

Now I know that I need to get the row 3 2 into a zero so I do $-2R+1 + R_3$

\begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 1 & 1 & 1           \\[0.3em]
       0 & 1           & 3 & 1 \\[0.3em]
       0 & -2         & -6 & -1
     \end{bmatrix}

Now I need the row 3 column 2 to be zero. so $2R_2 + R_3$
\begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 1 & 1 & 1           \\[0.3em]
       0 & 1           & 3 & 1 \\[0.3em]
       0 & 0         & 0 & 1
     \end{bmatrix}

This is inconsistent, was the step I did wrong or the system wrong? What went wrong? How do I find the rank and nullity on something that is inconsistent like this?

Comment: What do you mean $2x3$?

Comment: @Amzoti When talking about a matrix you call them by their rows and columns, and it is always rows and then columns so I mean 2 rows by 3 columns. Obviously that is a typo. Are you confused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We perform the row operations:
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 4 & 2 \\
2 & 0 & -4 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
& \sim_{R_2 \gets R_2-R_1}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 3 & 1 \\
2 & 0 & -4 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
& \sim_{R_3 \gets R_3-2R_1}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 3 & 1 \\
0 & -2 & -6 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
& \sim_{R_3 \gets R_3+2R_2}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 3 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\end{align*}
to obtain the [row echelon form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form) (in agreement with the OP's work).

It doesn't really make sense to talk about consistency here; it's just a matrix, not a system of equations.

We've shown that the row echelon form has $3$ leading $1$'s and thus the matrix has rank $3$, and thus the [Rank-Nullity Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) implies it has nullity $1$.

Comment: Oh ok I was more concerned with what to do when I run into a situation like that representing a system of equations. Does it always mean it is inconsistent and do I really need to get reduced row echelon form to see that I have a rank of 3? I mean even what i have isn't reduced and I got the right answer.

Comment: If it were an augmented matrix, then it would be inconsistent.  But this doesn't stop us finding the row echelon form and reduced row echelon form in the same way.

Comment: But do I need the reduced row echelon form always to find the rank?

Comment: Don't need the reduced row echelon form, just the [row echelon form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Rank_from_row_echelon_forms).

Comment: Alright thanks.